# get the id from <tr> tag from Jquery Data tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm trying to make a table with Data Table, after selecting a row, there is a button that takes the user to a new page with more detailed information.

after following the tutorial here https://datatables.net/examples/api/select_single_row.html

I'm thinking of setting  the `<tr id="ID">` to a unique identifier, and upon selecting the row then pressing the button, it will pass along the id and get more detailed information.

however I'm having difficulty getting this id field, I'm looking for something like

```
  $('#detailButton').click(function(){
    window.location = 'detail.php?id=' + table.row('.selected').id;
  });
```

EDIT:
Sorry to clarify, i only wanted 1 button at the bottom of the page, not one button per row, also not on clicking the row.
in the tutorial, when the row is selected, it sets the class to 'selected' so I was hoping to get the id of the row that has the class selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with the `$(this)` jQuery element you get the element which triggered the `event`. If you have an event that fires when a row is selected you can get the element and find the id.

HTML:

```
<table style="width:300px">
    <tr id="row0">
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td>Smith</td> 
        <td>50</td>
        <td>
            <button class="rowButton">select</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row1">
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td> 
        <td>94</td>
        <td>
            <button class="rowButton">select</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$('.rowButton').on('click', function(){
    window.location = 'detail.php?id=' + $(this).closest('tr').attr('id'); // read id from tr element
});
```

or

```
$('table tr').on('click', 'button', function(){
    window.location = 'detail.php?id=' + $(this).parents('tr').attr('id'); // read id from tr element
});
```

Comment: what I was looking for was actually just the attr('id') piece, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would assume there's a button per each row, in which case each button will need to have a unique id, which needs to refer somehow to the row. 
Another option would be to get the button offset within the table, thus determining in which row the button is located, like: button.parentNode can give you the row where the button is located. But I'm not sure what your html looks like.